# Response from model.fit: The last dimension of the inputs to `Dense` should be defined. Found `None`

Tags: keras, deep-learning

I am self-teaching myself Deep Learning methods using TensorFlow 2.0 and Keras. The scenario I chose was figuring out if a microwave is on based on a houses's aggregated electricity readings.  I explain this better in a [colab notebook](https://github.com/BitKnitting/transfer_nilm_exploration/blob/master/ExploreNILM_1.ipynb).

My goal is to replicate the learning model presented on the diagram shown in the colab notebook.  The notebook explains my input and target data.

I expected to be able to run model.fit on what I have set up in the layers. However, I am getting `The last dimension of the inputs to`Dense`should be defined. Found`None`.`

I must be misunderstanding setting up the input/output shapes.

I have tried various reshaping.  However, I am not able to understand how to correctly set up the tensors to the layers?

Here is the relevant code that is in the colab notebook:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Reshape((-1,599,1)))
model.add(Conv2D(filters=30,kernel_size=(10,1),strides=(1,1),padding='same',activation='relu',input_shape=(599,1)))
model.add(Conv2D(filters=30,kernel_size=(8,1),strides=(1,1),padding='same',activation='relu'))
model.add(Conv2D(filters=40,kernel_size=(6,1),strides=(1,1),padding='same',activation='relu'))
model.add(Conv2D(filters=50,kernel_size=(5,1),strides=(1,1),padding='same',activation='relu'))
model.add(Conv2D(filters=50,kernel_size=(5,1),strides=(1,1),padding='same',activation='relu'))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(1024,activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='linear', name='output'))

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='mean_squared_error',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(dataset, epochs=10)
WARNING:tensorflow:Layer sequential_2 is casting an input tensor from dtype float64 to the layer's dtype of float32, which is new behavior in TensorFlow 2.  The layer has dtype float32 because it's dtype defaults to floatx.

If you intended to run this layer in float32, you can safely ignore this warning. If in doubt, this warning is likely only an issue if you are porting a TensorFlow 1.X model to TensorFlow 2.

To change all layers to have dtype float64 by default, call `tf.keras.backend.set_floatx('float64')`. To change just this layer, pass dtype='float64' to the layer constructor. If you are the author of this layer, you can disable autocasting by passing autocast=False to the base Layer constructor.

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-21-f8c5e0c71664> in <module>()
----> 1 model.fit(dataset, epochs=10)

11 frames
/tensorflow-2.0.0/python3.6/tensorflow_core/python/keras/layers/core.py in build(self, input_shape)
   1013     input_shape = tensor_shape.TensorShape(input_shape)
   1014     if tensor_shape.dimension_value(input_shape[-1]) is None:
-> 1015       raise ValueError('The last dimension of the inputs to `Dense` '
   1016                        'should be defined. Found `None`.')
   1017     last_dim = tensor_shape.dimension_value(input_shape[-1])

ValueError: The last dimension of the inputs to `Dense` should be defined. Found `None`.
```

(Thank you)

Comment: Please add the relevant code in your question, not as an external link

Comment: You have to put the input_shape in the first layer of the model (The Reshape one)

Comment: Yes  Thank you.  You have been very helpful.  I apologize for my slow learning.  I struggle with getting tensor shapes right.